# Using mimetype 'application/octet-stream' with SAF picker works for local files but not for the same files in Google Drive

Tags: android, mime-types, storage-access-framework

I'm refactoring my backup/restore feature to work with Storage Access Framework. My backups are zip files with custom extensions (.dtt). If I try to open the picker with the following code, my .dtt files are selectable from the local Downloads directory but not from a directory in Google Drive. How can I make the file selectable even from Google Drive?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_SAF_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Notice how the backup file is selectable from the local "Downloads" directory, but grayed out in the Google Drive "backups" directory:

[image: local Downloads directory]

[image: Google Drive directory]

I know this behavior can be achieved, because NovaLauncher's restore feature behaves correctly.

Comment: You may peek their intent with this tool: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Unfortunately, it's not picking up the Intent that NovaLauncher is using. I'm not getting any kind of chooser before the SAF picker opens.

Comment: `intent.setType("*/*");`

Comment: @blackapps I could, but I want the picker to gray out the files that aren't my backup files. NovaLauncher does this somehow (or at least their implementation grays out most other files, as it still lets other binary files through).

Comment: Make your own picker. But why arent your files in one specific directory. You would not have that problem then.

Comment: @blackapps Don't I have to use SAF starting in August?

Comment: Yes you use SAF to make your own picker. Its just listing files and putting in a list view. You can then show what you want.

Comment: @blackapps I'm confused enough as it is with this refactor. Are there any picker libraries that use SAF? I haven't found a single one.

Comment: I dont know. I only suggested you write your own saf picker.

Comment: I would be careful about choosing "application/octet-stream" as it is a default. Note: Users can upload any file type to Drive using the Drive UI and Drive attempts to detect and automatically set the MIME type. If the MIME type can't be detected, the MIME type is set to application/octet-stream. [Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution. It looks like Google Drive changes the mime type of my files to "application/x-zip" upon uploading them. So I need to account for both mime types in order to make my files selectable in both places:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimeTypes = {"application/octet-stream","application/x-zip"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_SAF_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

If there's a better solution, or some sort of problem with this one, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I'm running into basically the same issue as you and arrived at the same solution, and I also can't figure it out. When I am saving a file to local storage, it isn't respecting the mime type that I'm setting in the intent; instead the mime type is entirely dependent on the file extension. But when I save it to Google Drive it correctly sets the mime type to the value I have in setType. Very frustrating.